# Создание базы данных в postgres через sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Мне необходимо создать базу данных, но мои попытки безуспешны, пока только разбираюсь в этом.

```
engine = create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:12345@localhost/name_db')
if not database_exists(engine.url):
    create_database(engine.url)
    insert_db()
```